# Make Sidebar items in Finder larger without affecting any other application

Tags: finder, icon, system-settings, sidebar

#### Background

I'd like to make items in the Finder's Sidebar larger like this:

[image]

Theoretically, you can do it like [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sidebar-how-to-make-sidebar-icons-smaller.1191888/):

1. Open *System Preferences*.
2. Open *General*.
3. Set *Sidebar icon size:* to *Medium* or *Large*.

[image]

#### Problem

Unfortunately, it affects not only the Sidebar in Finder but also in iTunes and so on.

Is it possible to make Sidebar items larger for Finder exclusively?

Comment: I don't believe so, or at least not built in to OS X.

Comment: @Appelflapper. I thought so. Maybe someone will come up with a nice software solution for that.